# NSTableView may not respond to "_LocationOfColumn"

Tags: cocoa

Trying to squash this warning / bug in my code not sure how to approach this error. Everything in the code works so I am unclear as to why its throwing this error.

"Warning: NSTableView may not respond to "_LocationOfColumn

`- (void) _locationOfColumn: (int) aColumn
    {
    SampleListArrayController *arrayController;
    arrayController = (SampleListArrayController *) SampleListController;`

```
if(( [ arrayController libraryIsSelected ] ) && ( aColumn == 4 ))
{
    return;
}
[ super _locationOfColumn: aColumn ]; <-- Error on this line.
}
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: How many column do you have in tableview??

Comment: And one more thing this is not the tableview method _locationOfColumn so you are getting this warning

Comment: And why you have written this method what it is performing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as i mentioned in my comments your method does not respond to the tableview. So i would recommend that in spite of using your custom method for detrmining location of column use below `NSTableView` delegate method which will Sent to the delegate to allow or prohibit the specified column to be dragged to a new location.:-

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
 shouldReorderColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex toColumn:(NSInteger)newColumnIndex
```